# in the core web vitals, a lot of my pages have same issues in css

Tags: page-speed

I have LCP issue and I am not able to solve these problem. please help me. In the core web vitals section, about 1339 pages of my site have lcp problems and most of them have the same problem and I don't know how to fix this.

I've attached one of these issue
[image]

Comment: You really need to do a sample page with minimum code that still reproduces this.

Answer (score 2):

> In the core web vitals section, about 1339 pages of my site have lcp problems

I presume you are talking about Core Web Vitals section of Google Search Console?

> I've attached one of these issue

This shows the Lighthouse test of a page. It actually shows a pretty healthy LCP of 1,390 milliseconds - well below the 2,500 millisecond LCP recommended "Good" threshold.

This means this test may not be representative of the issues your real-world users are seeing.

There's lots more details of how to user the other real-world data available in [PageSpeed Insights](https://pagespeed.web.dev/) in the [Google docs on Optimizing LCP](https://web.dev/articles/optimize-lcp#understanding_your_lcp_metric). Suggest you start there to see if you can narrow down the effect.

Quite often this is due to high TTFB rather than issues on the site. This means it's taking a long time to get to your site and that is eating up all the LCP time meaning it's impossible to get the recommended LCP time. TTFB is incluced in LCP as it is time experienced by the user - they feel that pain. If this is the case then you can check out the [Optimizing TTFB guide](https://web.dev/articles/optimize-ttfb) and there is also [a good section on that in this guide](https://web.dev/articles/optimize-cwv-business#delays_in_starting_to_load_the_page).

Full disclosure - I work at Google on the Core Web Vital initiative and contributed to these docs.